# cart.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, django, web, button, e-commerce

please answer this question i'm working on ecommerce website following the youtube chhanel name Dennis lvy https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCTZRcDjjkVajGL6wd76UnGg and i got this error in my js file

```
var updateBtns =  document.getElementByClassName('update-cart')


for(var i=0;i<updateBtns.length; i++){

    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', funcation(){
      var productId = this.dataset.product
      var action = this.dataset.action
      console.log('productId:', product, 'action:',action)

    })
}
```

error in line 6 updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', funcation(){ like cart.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list can anyone tell me how can i solve it?

```
<button data-product={{product.id}} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling is wrong for function try this :

```
       updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

           var productId = this.dataset.product;
           var action = this.dataset.action; 
           console.log('productId:', product, 'action:',action);
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `function` (not `funaction`). You also misspelled `getElementsByClassName` ([link to docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName))

Comment: yeah Marti you're right thank you so much for help :)